# Is traffic between Google products free?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, network-traffic

I have seen the statement that "outbound traffic from GCP to other Google products (such as Google Drive) is free".
I would like to confirm if this statement is true？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find a list of all the use case for GCP to non-GCP product traffic costs at this [page](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing). Section "VM-to-Google service".

But your initial statement is correct, traffic from a VM in GCP to Drive is free regardless of if the VM has a public or private IP. That's because that traffic never leaves Google backbone

Answer (score 1):

This is only true, while transferring data on the internal network `10.0.0.0`.
When using the public network (external IP), you'll be charged for the traffic.